# Django url.py rewrite to a different host

Tags: python, django, django-urls

this was my **url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'/newm/$', views.CreateManView.as_view(), name='create_man'),
```

I've changed it to:

```
url(r'http://y.y.y.y/newm/$', views.CreateManView.as_view(), name='create_man'),
```

but result in a call to:

> http://x.x.x.x/http://y.y.y.y/newm/

how can I change all url that refer to *create_man* so they will get to

> http://y.y.y.y/newm/

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [django-hosts](https://github.com/jezdez/django-hosts), it does exactly that.

As for having it as a feature in Django, a core dev commented on [this question](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8896):

> This has been solved by external apps and I'm happy with that solution

Comment: Actually, there's a fair chance this feature will land in 1.9, as part of my work to rewrite the URL dispatcher. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/WQoJN_MGTOg.